# array value arrange by selected value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array below:

```
$days = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0);
```

My selected value is `4` and I can get an array like:

```
$result = array(4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3);
```

With the code below:

```
$days = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0);
$split_by = array_search(4, $days);
if ($split_by) {
    $first = array_slice($days, 0, $split_by);
    $second = array_slice($days, $split_by);
}
$result = array_merge($second, $first);
print_r($result);
```

But when I pass selected value as `1` then it gives me null array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$split_by` is index `0` when you search for `1` and `0` equates loosely to `false`, so your `if` statement fails and the `$first` and `second` arrays are not created.  Do a strict comparison to `false`:

```
if ($split_by !== false) {
```

You also might want to do the merge in the `if` as well:

```
if ($split_by !== false) {
    $first = array_slice($days, 0, $split_by);
    $second = array_slice($days, $split_by);
    $result = array_merge($second, $first);
} else {
    $result = false; //or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   It will be work fine now use the code :

     $days = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0);
     $split_by = array_search(1, $days);
    if (isset($split_by)) {
        $first = array_slice($days, 0, $split_by);
        $second = array_slice($days, $split_by);
    }
    $result = array_merge($second, $first);
    print_r($result);
```